# Read value from one aspx page to another

Tags: user-controls, html, data-transfer

i have two pages: 1) web control(ascx page) and 2) web page(aspx page without master page).
Now i calculate some values on page2 through google api through Javascript on render, and i need to transfer these values to page 1 in a hidden field through code. please help

Khushi

Comment: Help with doing what? You describe your problem, but what have you tried? Normally to send data from one to another page you can use different options.

Comment: i have the web page which gives me the values. But if i try getting those values through WebRequet, it does not work because the values are genetrated by javascript on load.

Answer (score 0):

One way (of many):

- On the Client side: Fill the hidden
  field, submit the form (with js)
- Code Behind
  Page 2: Collect the data in the code
  behind, Populate the session,
  Response.Redirect to page 1

Another:

- Without using the the hidden field, you could
  just append the calculation result to
  the query string. (/page.aspx?myResult=xy)

Answer (score 0):

Obvious, quick answer: use querystring or Session object.